# How do I FFI a CUDA application on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cuda, linker, ghc, ffi

I've ported a Haskell application to CUDA in order to accelerate it. Now, I have a `.cu` file which I want to call from Haskell as an API. I've managed to FFI C files easily by following tutorials, but I'm not sure how this applies to CUDA/nvcc. How do I access symbols defined in CUDA source files through the FFI?

For completion, this is what I get trying to treat the `.cu` as a normal `.c` file:

```
vh:CUDA apple1$ nvcc hello.cu -c -o hello.o
vh:CUDA apple1$ ghc test.hs -o test hello.o
Linking test ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___cudaRegisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __sti____cudaRegisterAll_40_tmpxft_00002168_00000000_7_hello_cpp1_ii_f33df8d2() in hello.o
  "___cudaRegisterFunction", referenced from:
      __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**) in hello.o
  "___cudaUnregisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil() in hello.o
  "_cudaConfigureCall", referenced from:
      render(Renderer_*) in hello.o
  "_cudaFree", referenced from:
      renderer_free(Renderer_*) in hello.o
  "_cudaLaunch", referenced from:
      cudaError cudaLaunch<char>(char*) in hello.o
  "_cudaMalloc", referenced from:
      renderer_init(Renderer_*, float, float, float, float, float) in hello.o
  "_cudaMemcpy", referenced from:
      renderer_init(Renderer_*, float, float, float, float, float) in hello.o
      render(Renderer_*) in hello.o
  "_cudaSetupArgument", referenced from:
      __device_stub__Z4walk6float3PiS_S_S_S_S0_(float3&, int*, float3&, float3&, float3&, float3&, int*) in hello.o
  "_hello", referenced from:
      _r3yw_info in test.o
      _c3Ib_info in test.o
      _c3Il_info in test.o
     (maybe you meant: _Main_hello_closure, _Main_hello_info )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is my Haskell file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main where

import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr,nullPtr)

foreign import ccall "hello" hello :: IO ()

main = hello
```

Comment: you will probably need to link in the cuda runtime library

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve it by adding `extern "C"` to all functions on `hello.cu`:

```
-- hello.cu
extern "C" 
void hello();
```

Compiling the CUDA file with:

```
nvcc -c hello.cu
```

And the Haskell file with:

```
ghc --make test.hs -o test hello.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -optl-lcudart
```

Comment: ... let me know if there is a better answer.

Comment: I don't think better answer exist, you just use a proper and portable ABI (with `extern "C"`) and just link with CUDA library.